# Access to private Github project board

Tags: github, project, project-management

Is it possible to give read-only access to private Github project boards?  Not to the code projects, just to the boards?  The code is for developers but other people in the company should be able to see the status of various projects.

Also, is such access free?  I'm setting this up for a small startup and funds are still tight.  I don't want to make it expensive for them to get help from friends and family.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give access to read or write access to repositories, but it does not provide access like this, but you can look for permission information on this link.
https://help.github.com/articles/permission-levels-for-an-organization/

You can review the article at https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/team-collaboration-with-github--net-29876

We have used waffle in past and it works for providing status only. You can use Waffle for providing the status on different issues https://waffle.io without giving access.

Comment: Thank you.  I will have a look through those.  Waffle looks as if it might do the trick.